# Face detection with YOLO

Tags: face-detection

I'm writing code using Python for detecting face using live feed from my MacBook camera. Code does detect the camera but it turns off after 2 seconds and doesn't get any video feed. Below is my code:

```
detector = VideoObjectDetection()

detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()

detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))

detector.loadModel()

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) --This turn camera light 

video_path=detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=output_file_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "camera_detected_1"), frames_per_second=29, log_progress=True)

detector.detect
```

Let me know what I need to do differently.

Comment: Is that the entire program?

Comment: yes this is entire program